# How do I reset a variable value when triggering onclick events in a loop

Tags: javascript, html, css, ecmascript-6

I have several image galleries covering different categories, in the code below I've only included 2 (nature and urban) to make it easier to read. I am using a "for" loop with "let" before the onclick event so that any node within the HTML collection can be clicked on and I'll get the index. I am then applying this index to an array of identical images except they are HD rather than thumbnails.

The "rightArrow" and "leftArrow" div's are being used to move to the next or previous images in the array by increasing or decreasing the index by one, pretty standard. The issue is that when I exit fullscreen mode the index changes haven't been reset. Therefore when the user clicks on another image from the same gallery to re-open fullscreen mode they don't get the corresponding image.

So how do I reset the index before triggering the onclick event for "natureThumbnailImgs" and "urbanThumbnailImgs"? Or include something into the "exitFullscreen" event that resets the index?

Any help is very much appreciated,

Steve

```js
var fullscreen = document.getElementsByClassName("fullscreen");
var fullImg = document.getElementById("fullImg");
var exitFullscreen = document.getElementById("exitFullscreen");

var rightArrow = document.getElementById("rightArrow");
var leftArrow = document.getElementById("leftArrow");

exitFullscreen.onclick = function() {
        fullscreen[0].removeAttribute("id", "showFullscreen"); 
    }

var natureThumbnailImgs = document.getElementsByClassName("natureThumbnailImgs");
var natureHDImgs = ["1 nature HD.jpg", "2 nature HD.jpg", "3 nature HD.jpg"];

// NATURE GALLERY ALBUM
for (let albumIndex = 0; albumIndex < natureThumbnailImgs.length; albumIndex++) {
        natureThumbnailImgs[albumIndex].onclick = function() {
            //DISPLAY FULLSCREEN
            fullscreen[0].setAttribute("id", "showFullscreen");
            //APPLY CHOSEN IMAGE
            fullImg.src = "../../../Image Bank/" + natureHDImgs[albumIndex];

            //NEXT
            rightArrow.onclick = function() {
                if (albumIndex < (natureThumbnailImgs.length - 1)) {
                    albumIndex++;
                    //APPLY CHOSEN IMAGE
                    fullImg.src = "../../../Image Bank/" + natureHDImgs[albumIndex];
                }
            }
            
            //PREV
            leftArrow.onclick = function() {
                if (albumIndex > 0) {
                    albumIndex--;
                    //APPLY CHOSEN IMAGE
                    fullImg.src = "../../../Image Bank/" + natureHDImgs[albumIndex];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
var urbanThumbnailImgs = document.getElementsByClassName("urbanThumbnailImgs");
var urbanHDImgs = ["1 urban HD.jpg", "2 urban HD.jpg", "3 urban HD.jpg"];
    
// URBAN GALLERY ALBUM 
for (let albumIndex = 0; albumIndex < urbanThumbnailImgs.length; albumIndex++) {
    urbanThumbnailImgs[albumIndex].onclick = function() {
        //DISPLAY FULLSCREEN
        fullscreen[0].setAttribute("id", "showFullscreen");
        //APPLY CHOSEN IMAGE
        fullImg.src = "../../../Image Bank/" + urbanHDImgs[albumIndex];

        //NEXT
        rightArrow.onclick = function() {
            if (albumIndex < (urbanThumbnailImgs.length - 1)) {
                albumIndex++;
                //APPLY CHOSEN IMAGE
                fullImg.src = "../../../Image Bank/" + urbanHDImgs[albumIndex];
            }
        }

        //PREV
        leftArrow.onclick = function() {
            if (albumIndex > 0) {
                albumIndex--;
                //APPLY CHOSEN IMAGE
                fullImg.src = "../../../Image Bank/" + urbanHDImgs[albumIndex];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```css
[class$="ThumbnailImgs"] {
  width: 100px;
  height: auto;
}

#fullscreen {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: 1;
}

#fullscreen {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  right: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
  <title>Image Gallery</title>
  <link href="css/IG.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>

<!-- NATURE ALBUM -->
  <div id="natureAlbum">
    <img class="natureThumbnailImgs" src="../../../Image Bank/1 nature thumbnail.jpeg"/>
    <img class="natureThumbnailImgs" src="../../../Image Bank/2 nature thumbnail.jpeg"/>
    <img class="natureThumbnailImgs" src="../../../Image Bank/3 nature thumbnail.jpeg"/>
  </div>

<!-- URBAN ALBUM -->
  <div id="urbanAlbum">
    <img class="urbanThumbnailImgs" src="../../../Image Bank/1 urban thumbnail.jpeg"/>
    <img class="urbanThumbnailImgs" src="../../../Image Bank/2 urban thumbnail.jpeg"/>
    <img class="urbanThumbnailImgs" src="../../../Image Bank/3 urban thumbnail.jpeg"/>
  </div>

<!-- FULL IMG DISPLAY -->
  <div id="fullscreen">
    <div id="exitFullscreen">X</div>
    <img id="fullImg" src=""/>
    <div id="leftArrow">Left Arrow Symbol</div>
    <div id="rightArrow">Right Arrow Symbol</div>
  </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try not updating the album index in the first place - take a copy of it each time a thumbnail is clicked. The pattern for a single gallery might look like:

```
// NATURE GALLERY ALBUM
for (let albumIndex = 0; albumIndex < natureThumbnailImgs.length; albumIndex++) {
        natureThumbnailImgs[albumIndex].onclick = function() {
            index = albumIndex;   // copy the base album index
            //DISPLAY FULLSCREEN
            fullscreen[0].setAttribute("id", "showFullscreen");
            //APPLY CHOSEN IMAGE
            fullImg.src = "../../../Image Bank/" + natureHDImgs[index];

            //NEXT
            rightArrow.onclick = function() {
                if (index < (natureThumbnailImgs.length - 1)) {
                    index++;
                    //APPLY CHOSEN IMAGE
                    fullImg.src = "../../../Image Bank/" + natureHDImgs[index];
                }
            }

            //PREV
            leftArrow.onclick = function() {
                if (index > 0) {
                    index--;
                    //APPLY CHOSEN IMAGE
                    fullImg.src = "../../../Image Bank/" + natureHDImgs[index];
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This should at least produce a different behavior than the posted code.

Answer (score 1):

I apologize for the delay, i ended up working through your code quite a bit, there are a number of things to do here:

Check the demo:
https://codesandbox.io/s/lx4x66rq9

Points:

- create an index attribute on each image that will help you track what you are clicking
- store the hd path for the image as a data attribute on the image
- create a seperate variable to track what the active image is, and clear it when closing the fullscreen

The JS:

```js
var fullscreen = document.getElementsByClassName("fullscreen");
var fullImg = document.getElementById("fullImg");
var exitFullscreen = document.getElementById("exitFullscreen");
var urbanThumbnailImgs = document.getElementsByClassName("urbanThumbnailImgs");
var activeImage = 0;

exitFullscreen.onclick = function() {
  fullscreen[0].removeAttribute("id", "showFullscreen");
  activeImage = 0;
};

var natureThumbnailImgs = document.getElementsByClassName(
  "natureThumbnailImgs"
);

// NATURE GALLERY ALBUM
createImages(natureThumbnailImgs);
createImages(urbanThumbnailImgs);

function createImages(images) {
  for (var albumIndex = 0; albumIndex < images.length; albumIndex++) {
    images[albumIndex].setAttribute("data-index", albumIndex);
    images[albumIndex].onclick = function(el) {
      fullscreen[0].setAttribute("id", "showFullscreen");
      fullImg.src = el.target.dataset.hd;

      var rightArrow = document.getElementById("rightArrow");
      var leftArrow = document.getElementById("leftArrow");

      activeImage = parseInt(el.target.dataset.index);

      //NEXT
      rightArrow.onclick = function() {
        if (activeImage < images.length - 1) {
          activeImage++;
          fullImg.src = images[activeImage].dataset.hd;
        }
      };

      //PREV
      leftArrow.onclick = function() {
        if (activeImage > 0) {
          activeImage--;
          fullImg.src = images[activeImage].dataset.hd;
        }
      };
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: I have tried that. It stops the albumIndex from being selected within the "for" loops. It will remain at 0. I would put the loop into a function because it would definitely help being able to control the scope more precisely but I need the loop to happen before the event so that any of the HTML collection nodes can be chosen. How would you put it into a function whilst it still working in this way?